# Knoppix cheat code permanency

Tags: knoppix

What do I need to do to make the cheat codes I use to start up Knoppix, which has been installed to an SSD permanent? For example, I want to use "knoppix64 no3d tz=Asia/Shanghai" every single time I boot without needing to type it in. Can this be done, and if so, how?

Comment: You need to modify the boot loader to pass the *kernel options* into the kernel when it's booted up. Many distros use Grub or Grub2, and have a `grub.cfg` file or something like that which you can edit to add them. Hopefully someone with more recent experience can expand this into a proper answer.

Comment: cheat code? don't you mean console command lines?

Comment: No, they are referred to as cheat codes. You can perform a search for Knoppix cheat codes and come back with all sorts of hits showing all the available options. A link to such a site is http://www.pendrivelinux.com/knoppix-cheatcodes/

Comment: i see. disregard my last comment then. im way more used to (very) small distros (slitaz per example) than i am to Knoppix. funny they are referred to as "cheatcodes" tho.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `/home/knoppix/Desktop/KNOPPIX/boot/isolinux/isolinux.cfg`.  Append the desired options to the line starting with `APPEND` located in the default boot string.  The default boot string is specified at the beginning of the isolinux.cfg file.  For example, Knoppix 7.2 isolinux.cfg starts with

```
DEFAULT knoppix
APPEND lang=en apm=power-off initrd=minirt.gz nomce libata.force=noncq hpsa.hpsa_allow_any=1 loglevel=1
```

Look for the line starting with `LABEL Knoppix`.  Below this line is a line starting with `APPEND`.  At the end of the `APPEND` string, add the options that you want to be active when you boot the default options.  Using your question, you would add your options so that the default boot options would be

```
DEFAULT knoppix
APPEND lang=en apm=power-off initrd=minirt.gz nomce libata.force=noncq hpsa.hpsa_allow_any=1 loglevel=1 no3d tz=Asia/Shanghai
```